# iPhone USB connection is disconnected by apple-mfi-fastcharge driver

Tags: drivers, files, usb-modem, iphone, apple

When I connect the iPhone to the USB-C terminal of my laptop, I don't find my iPhone in my files.
Found the cause of the error: cmd  'dmesg'

```
[ 7795.969752] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 7796.123675] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8, bcdDevice=12.08
[ 7796.123689] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7796.123694] usb 1-1: Product: iPhone
[ 7796.123698] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 7796.123702] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00008030234929A60E20402F
[ 7796.218089] ipheth 1-1:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
[ 7796.257849] ipheth 1-1:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet now disconnected
[ 7796.279873] apple-mfi-fastcharge 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

I feel that this is caused coz of the Apple-MFi driver, but not sure how to disable it.
Could someone help me in getting this fixed as I have very minimal knowledge in Linux drivers.

This happens only on my Ubuntu, while other users were able to connect to my iPhone as it always have been. The only difference I could see was  `apple-mfi-fastcharge 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6` was missing.

INFO:
I am using the latest Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS OS.
iPhone SE 2020 running iOS 16.0.3.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the info there not as a comment. As for the driver there does not appear to be one. It is using the USB driver the rest is in the phone. Maybe try an Apple site and see if anyone has some idea.

Comment: I don't think connecting with Apple community would really help, as I was able to connect my iPhone to other users' machine running UBUNTU.

Comment: The exact same version with the same updates and the same soft wares installed?

Comment: Yes. It was the exact version of Linux and iOS.

Comment: I also tried enabling Fast Change support for Apple devices from the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592775/how-can-i-enable-apple-ios-fast-charge-support). 
But was not able to find `99-iphone-fastcharge.rules`  in  ```/etc/udev/rules.d/99-iphone-fastcharge.rules```

Comment: I updated to latest Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, but the issues still persists.